# Wordpress images are gone and it's showing a 404 (Not Found) error

Tags: wordpress

The site was running smoothly and without any problems. I tried to deactivate my plugins to find out which one could be giving the error, but even after I did it the images are still gone and the error persists.

The site is: http://www.depurekeuken.nl/

Also the images are on the ftp where they should be. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: looking at your image srcs, they are using `http://www.depurekeuken.nl/new/...` URL, which seems to be a development area.  Try updating your image links to not have the `/new` subdirectory

Comment: if there are a lot of images on a lot of pages then you can do a SQL query to update the links, if its only a few images/pages then just edit the page/post with the Text editor and change the `<img src=...>` values

Answer (score 0):

the reason your images aren't showing up is that the links never got updated whenever you moved your WP installation up to the root directory from the `/new` subdirectory.  If there is only a handful of pages/images that are effected, it would be easiest just to update the links manually by using the Text editor in the Post/Page Edit screen.  If there are a lot of images/pages effected it is more efficient to do a SQL UPDATE statement. something like this should work for you

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, 'http://www.depurekeuken.nl/new', 'http://www.depurekeuken.nl') 
WHERE 1
```

Please note that i do not know your database so the query may not be 100% ready to go as it is above but it should be close enough, make sure to backup your database before running this SQL code as you cant undo the query if it goes wrong.  Also note that this will update EVERYTHING that matches `http://www.duprekeuken.nl/new` in your posts' contents, including links to other pages, which may actually be what you want as well.